# How to avoid recalculating a function when we need to backpropagate through it twice?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

In PyTorch, I want to do the following calculation:

```py
l1 = f(x.detach(), y)
l1.backward(retain_graph=True)
l2 = -1*f(x, y.detach())
l2.backward()
```

where `f` is some function, and `x` and `y` are tensors that require gradient. Notice that `x` and `y` may both be the results of previous calculations which utilize shared parameters (for example, maybe `x=g(z)` and `y=g(w)` where `g` is an `nn.Module`).

The issue is that `l1` and `l2` are both numerically identical, up to the minus sign, and it seems wasteful to repeat the calculation `f(x,y)` twice. It would be nicer to be able to calculate it once, and apply `backward` twice on the result. Is there any way of doing this?

One possibility is to manually call `autograd.grad` and update the `w.grad` field of each `nn.Parameter` `w`. But I'm wondering if there is a more direct and clean way to do this, using the `backward` function.

Comment: I don't see a way to avoid computing `f` twice in such a situation but you can avoid calling backward twice by letting `l = l1 + l2` followed by `l.backward()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this answer from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-avoid-recalculating-a-function-when-we-need-to-backpropagate-through-it-twice).

We can calculate `f(x,y)` once, without detaching neither `x` or `y`, if we ensure that we we multiply by `-1` the gradient flowing through `x`. This can be done using `register_hook`:

```py
x.register_hook(lambda t: -t)
l = f(x,y)
l.backward()
```

Here is code demonstrating that this works:

```py
import torch

lin = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)
lin.weight.data[:] = 1.0
a = torch.tensor([1.0])
b = torch.tensor([2.0])
loss_func = lambda x, y: (x - y).abs()

# option 1: this is the inefficient option, presented in the original question
lin.zero_grad()
x = lin(a)
y = lin(b)
loss1 = loss_func(x.detach(), y)
loss1.backward(retain_graph=True)
loss2 = -1 * loss_func(x, y.detach())  # second invocation of `loss_func` - not efficient!
loss2.backward()
print(lin.weight.grad)

# option 2: this is the efficient method, suggested in this answer. 
lin.zero_grad()
x = lin(a)
y = lin(b)
x.register_hook(lambda t: -t)
loss = loss_func(x, y)  # only one invocation of `loss_func` - more efficient!
loss.backward()
print(lin.weight.grad)  # the output of this is identical to the previous print, which confirms the method

# option 3 - this should not be equivalent to the previous options, used just for comparison
lin.zero_grad()
x = lin(a)
y = lin(b)
loss = loss_func(x, y)
loss.backward()
print(lin.weight.grad)
```